# Dialog width does not work in FireFox

Tags: jquery-ui

I do not understand why the dialog will not work for width in Firefox (latest version) but will in IE (latest version):

```
dialogDiv.dialog
(
    {
        resizable: resizable,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'blind'
    }
)
```

No, it's not in a table..it's all tableless and I see it working fine in IE for width.

Comment: can you show use the html and where you get the width and height from as well as how your getting the selector ?

Comment: I just send in the width and height and set them to local var width and var height in my functoin that contains what you see above.  Pretty simple, no strings attached here.

Comment: its often better to supply more information than less it can help solve problems faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the problem by puting the width and height in as a string rather and in integer in one of my ui dialogs so I would suggest checking that

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell u it needs to be integer

Answer (score 0):

Check 2 places:

- Must use integer value, not string, for width.
- Clear cached JavaScript file from Firefox and try it again. To clear, go to Options -- Advanced -- Network -- Cached Web Content -- Clear Now. If you do not want to clear your Firefox cache, rename your JavaScript file.